# Can we handle OS pop-up using "gem sikuli" in selenium script

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, jruby, sikuli

[image]

When I hit url in browser it gives windows authentication pop-up and we need to enter proper username and password into that then only it will give home page of that site.

- It is not able to handle windows pop-up using Selenium-WebDriver
- I was trying to handle that pop-up using gem sikuli code inside selenium script but it is giving error as

> Timeout::Error: execution expired

Comment: give that screenshot in your post also...

Comment: Hi @Priti added screen-shot :)

Comment: Yeah!! I am seeing.. that. give me just `html` content of the *username* and *password*...

Comment: No not possible to give you HTML because it is OS pop-up. if I get html I can automate that. You can't inspect that element using selenium , you can't interact with browser until you close that pop-up or click 'OK' by entering valid username and password. It is a OS pop-up.

Comment: don't delete the post. I am working on this.I think it is possible.. But my firefox got upgraded,thus I am down-grading it. thus taking time..

Comment: NO I was trying to edit the comment , so I deleted it and retyped it. Thanks!!

Comment: can you join here ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33767/selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

OS pop ups cannot be handled using Selenium Web Driver , however there are numerous other frameworks that can handle it. This is for a upload window , thus should work for your scenario too.

[This is what I use in C#](http://cheryjose.blogspot.com/2013/03/automate-user-actions-done-on-plupload.html)

Answer (score 0):

driver.get("http://LOGIN:PASSWORD@localhost:8080/myApp/")

LOGIN> -> username which you need pass for authentication

PASSWORD> -> password which you need pass for authentication

After @ put your URL.

Don't forget to put / at the end of the URL, At-least for firefox.